# Arduino serial only works with PuTTY and not pySerial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to communicate with an Arduino Pro Micro over Serial. I am using pySerial in Python to send commands.

pySerial is not working, however this does work in PuTTY.

```
# Import libraries
import serial
from time import sleep

# Global Variables
port = 'COM5'
baudrate = 9600

arduino = serial.Serial( port, baudrate, timeout=0 )

# Start Serial interface
try:
    print("Connecting to Arduino on: " + port + " (" + str(baudrate) + ")")
    sleep(3)
    arduino.write( b'cs 4' )
    arduino.write( b'dt 0 0 hi' )
    arduino.flushOutput()
finally:
    arduino.close()
```

Comment: HOW are you determining that this isn't working?  One thing that looks suspicious is that you aren't sending any line-ending characters at all - just the text ``cs 4dt 0 0 hi`` and nothing else.  I suspect that you were hitting Return after each line in PuTTY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idiot that I am, I forgot to add carriage return and newline to the strings that I  was sending.

I have wasted two hours because I forgot to add `\r\n` to the end of the strings.
Thank you, @jasonharper for pointing out my stupidity.

I hope you will find amusement from the fact that it took me 2 hours to write 'hi' on a display.